# Как отсортировать двумерный vector

Tags: c++, vector

Есть условный, уже инициализированный 2х вектор:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = { {3,2,1,4,5},{3,2,4,1,5} };
```

Как его можно отсортировать?

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Отрабатывает, но не сортирует.

Я так понимаю нужен итератор для работы с колонками вектора? Но как его инициализировать? Или какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: Проитерироватся и отсортировать, если нужно все значения в  векторе сортировать его нужно превратить в одномерный вектор сначала

Comment: Тут бы сначала решить, как собственно вы хотите его отсортировать. Лексикографически? Приведите примеры.

Comment: а как нужно сортировать лично вам?...

Comment: стандартно.по возрастанию

Comment: @ishidex2 ок. итераторы. два вложенных цикла for. в первом цикле я указываю рамки  iter=vec.begin(); iter< vec.end() iter ++. А во втором какие рамки я должен указать?

Comment: Можете показать, как будет выглядеть вектор из вопроса после сортировки?

Comment: Вам нужно отсортировать все с сохранением размера? или просто отсортировать строки в матрице? @HolyBlackCat - Вы тоже подумали о сортировке всего содержимого?

Comment: @Andrey И об этом тоже. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat vec = { {1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5} };

Comment: @Максим То есть каждый из под-векторов отсортировать отдельно?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да. то, что написал AR Hovsepyan мне подходит

Comment: "Отрабатывает, но не сортирует"? Зачем вы нас обманываете? Ваш код все прекрасно сортирует. Внутренние векторы в составе внешнего сортируются лексикографически. Ваш пример просто уже и так лексикографически отсортирован. Попробуйте поменять местами исходные векторы в примере.

Comment: "то, что написал AR Hovsepyan мне подходит". Прекрасно. Но почему тогда полное условие задачи не указано в вопросе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сортировать вектор векторов, например так:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec =
    { {3,2,1,4,5},{3,2,4,1,5}, {5, 6,2} };
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    [](const auto& v1, const auto& v2) 
    { return v1.size() < v2.size(); });
```

и можете сортировать вектора_элементы(думаю вам это нужно):

```
for (auto& v : vec) {
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());          
}
```

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan точняк! последний вариант мой, спасибо!